# Issues with 'movement' across multi-dimensional array, text-based game

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently messing around with the code right now to solve some issues in movement. Ideally, i want to be able to move the character to any spot in the array(worldMap) containing ' ', and marking the player's position with 'P'.

I'm lost to what the issue I am running into is, and some of the issues I am running into are as follows...
- when I move E it always goes to worldMap[3][3]
- N only moves up from worldMap[3][x] to worldMap [2][x]
- S doesn't work

Below is my current code...

```
    import math
    import random
    import sys
    import os
    import time



    gameplay= True
    #world map lay out, X--> wall, player can't go that way. ' ', possible area for player to move, 'P', player indicator.

    worldMap = [['X','X','X','X','X'],
                ['X',' ',' ',' ','X'],
                ['X',' ',' ',' ','X'],
                ['X','P',' ',' ','X'],
                ['X','X','X','X','X']]
    west=str("w" or "W")
    east=str("e" or "E")
    north=str('n' or 'N')
    south=str('s' or 'S')

    for row in worldMap:
        for column in row:
            print(column, end=' ')
        print()


    while gameplay == True:
        x=str((input("\nWhat direction would you like to move?\n ")))
        if x==west:
            for row in worldMap:
                for i, column in enumerate(row):
                    if column == 'P':
                        if((i>0) and (i<4) and row[i-1]) == ' ':
                            row[i-1] = 'P'
                            row[i]=' '
                        else:
                            print("\nCan't do that.\n")
            for row in worldMap:
                for column in row:
                    print(column, end=' ')
                print()
        elif x==east:
            for row in worldMap:
                for i, column in enumerate(row):
                    if column == 'P':
                        if((i>0) and (i<4) and row[i+1]) == ' ':
                            row[i+1] = 'P'
                            row[i]=' '
                        else:
                            print("\nCan't do that.\n")
            for row in worldMap:
                for column in row:
                    print(column, end=' ')
                print()
        elif x == north: #move north
            for column in worldMap:
                for i, row in enumerate(column):
                    if row == 'P':
                        if((i>0) and (i<4) and column[i-1]) == ' ':
                            column[i-1] = 'P'
                            column[i]=' '
                        else:
                            print("\nCan't do that.\n")
            for row in worldMap:
                for column in row:
                    print(column, end=' ')
                print()
        elif x== south: #move south
            for column in worldMap:
                for i, row in enumerate(column):
                    if column == 'P':
                        if((i>0) and (i<4) and column[i+1]) == ' ':
                            column[i+1] = 'P'
                            column[i]=' '
                        else:
                            print("\nCan't do that.\n")
            for row in worldMap:
                for column in row:
                    print(column, end=' ')
                print()
        else:
            for row in worldMap:
                for column in row:
                    print(column, end=' ')
                print()
            print("\nCan't do that.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tided up your code a bit. A good clue to needing to refactor your code is if you have written the same thing alot in your code. In those cases its better to write a function and then call the function from your code. The below code is just an example to help set you on the right path.

In this example instead of scanning the whole map for the player, i just keep track of the players position and calculate the new position and if its a space then move the player. We can easily move the player by adding or subtracting 1 to the x or y co-ordinate of the player.

I also cleaned up the print map function and its now only called at the start of each loop.

```py
from random import randint
def generate_map(size):
    # world map lay out, X--> wall, player can't go that way. ' ', possible area for player to move, 'P', player indicator.
    world_map = [[wall for _ in range(size)]]
    for i in range(1, size - 1):
        world_map.append([wall])
        for j in range(1, size - 1):
            #generate random walls in our map (currently set to genearete spaces 90% of the time
            if randint(1,100) < 90:
                world_map[i].append(space)
            else:
                world_map[i].append(wall)
        world_map[i].append(wall)
    world_map.append([wall for _ in range(size)])
    return world_map


def print_map():
    for row in worldMap:
        print(" ".join(row))


def move_player():
    x, y = player_position
    if direction == "W":
        y -= 1
    elif direction == "E":
        y += 1
    elif direction == "N":
        x -= 1
    elif direction == "S":
        x += 1

    if worldMap[x][y] == space:
        worldMap[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] = space
        worldMap[x][y] = player
        player_position[0] = x
        player_position[1] = y
    else:
        print("Cannot more there")

#Genearte a map and position the player
wall, space, player = "X", " ", "P"
map_size = 10
worldMap = generate_map(map_size)
player_position = [1, 1]
worldMap[player_position[0]][player_position[1]] = player

#Run the game
gameplay = True
while gameplay:
    print_map()
    direction = input("\nWhat direction would you like to move? ").upper()
    if direction:
        move_player()
    else:
        break
```